# Can't login over ssh - IO error?

Tags: login

I'm trying to log into a Raspberry Pi which is on my network over SSH, but when I enter the correct password, it responds with

```
-bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Inddata/uddata-fejl
-bash: /home/pi/.bashrc: Inddata/uddata-fejl
Connection to 192.168.0.91 closed.
```

I'm not sure what "Inddata/uddata-fejl" would be in english, but it roughly translates as "IO error".

Is there anything I can do (besides accessing the Pi physically)? What can cause this? I've never seen this error before.

Comment: I understand that this is happening on a half-broken system. On a working system, you would be expected to switch your system language to English before posting error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You get a disconnect because `bash` fails to open some files it relies on. Try connecting with a different shell, e.g.

```
ssh pi@192.168.0.91 sh
```

You may want to run `fsck` on your filesystem when you connect, to see if there's any damage besides the two above-mentioned files. In the end, if the root cause is a failed SD card, that cannot be fixed without physical access.

Comment: Interesting suggestion - I didn't know that you could specify a shell type at login. Unfortunately, it gives me the exact same errors in .bashrc. I'll probably have to find it ;-)

Comment: Using `sh` doesn't help. It's just a symlink to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @OZ1SEJ Try to use `dash` or `busybox sh` istead of `sh`. `busybox` should always work because its for rescue without any dependencies. If it doesn't run then the executable itself is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the file system is corrupt given that you get the error on two files.

I don't see what you can do from a remote location.